# Delete subarrays with elements of another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array `array_one` that contains consecutive subarrays of length K. I have another array `array_two` that contains some numbers, at least 2. Here is an example for K = 2:

```
array_one = [ [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7] ]
array_two = [ 4,6 ]
```

I want to remove all subarrays that contain at least one of the numbers of `array_two` or contain at least one of the numbers of a subarray that was deleted. All subarrays but `x[0]` get deleted with the given case.

Comment: K defines the length of the consecutive subarrays.

Comment: What does "consecutive subarrary" mean? The elements within each subarray are consecutive numbers?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! This is a fun little problem, that can be solved in two steps.

Step one is to remove items that contain array_two values.
The second step is to generate a list of the values removed in step one and repeat the same removal process.

```
array_one = [ [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7] ]
array_two = [ 4,6 ]

array_two_removed = array_one.reject{ |e| e.any? { |v| array_two.include? v } }
values_removed = (array_one - array_two_removed).flatten.uniq # gotta love array math to make this easy
final_answer = array_two_removed.reject{ |e| e.any? { |v| values_removed.include? v } }
```

---

```
# loop over the array that has the first pass removed.
final_answer = array_two_removed.reject do |subarray|
  # for each sub array, see if any of the removed values exist, if so it will be removed.
  subarray.any? do |subarray_value|
    values+removed.include? subarray_value|
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you give me a short explanation on how the iteration with the two blocks is working in detail?

Comment: Yes, what is happening is we are taking array and rejecting (taking out) any of the sub-arrays that contain one of the removed values.

Comment: Any? is needed because reject can not access the subarrays values directly?

Comment: no, reject has a hold of the subarray, so it would have no problem accessing the values. This was just how I implemented it. I tend not to over analyze and just go with what gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of your particular data structure, you can do this very efficiently, in a single pass.

**Assumption**

By "consecutive subarrays" I assume you mean, given integers `f` ("first") `n` and `k`:

```
arr1 = [[f,f+1,..,f+k-1], [[f+1,f+2,..,f+k],..., [f+n-1,f+n,..,f+n+k-2]
```

For your example:

```
f = 1
k = 2
n = 6
```

We can represent this array with a method that extracts the ith element:

```
def stab(f,k,n,i)
  f+i..f+k-1+i
end

arr1 = n.times.map { |i| stab(f,k,n,i).to_a }
  #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
```

**Code**

```
def extract(f,k,n,arr2)
   arr2.reduce(n.times.to_a) do |a,j|
     a-([j-2*k-f+2,0].max..[j+k-f-1,n-1].min).to_a
   end.map { |i| stab(f,k,n,i).to_a }
end
```

**Examples**

For your example:

```
f,k,n = 1,2,6
arr2 = [4,6]
extract(f,k,n,arr2)
  # => [[1, 2]]
```

For:

```
f, k, n = 2, 3, 18
```

which produces:

```
arr1 = n.times.map { |i| stab(f,k,n,i).to_a }
  #=> [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [ 5, 6, 7], [ 6, 7, 8],
  #    [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11], [10, 11, 12],
  #    [11, 12, 13], [12, 13, 14], [13, 14, 15], [14, 15, 16],
  #    [15, 16, 17], [16, 17, 18], [17, 18, 19], [18, 19, 20],
  #    [19, 20, 21]]
```

if:

```
arr2 = [7,15]
```

then:

```
extract(f,k,n,arr2)
  #=> [[2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12], [18, 19, 20], [19, 20, 21]]
```

**Explanation**

For any number `j`, we know that the indices of elements of `arr1` that contain `j` are given by the range:

```
b..e
b = j-f-k+1
e = j-f
```

(though we will need to ensure that the `b >= 0` and `e < n`).

For your example, if `j=4`, this range is `2..3`, that is, the elements `a = [[3,4], [4,5]]`.

Continuing with your example, consider the last element of the last element of `a`; that is, `5` (`4+k-1`). Applying the expression for the range `s..e` I derived above, `5` appears in elements of `arr1` given by indices in the range `b..e`, where:

```
b = 5-1-2+1 #=> 3
e = 5-1     #=> 4
```

We are only concerned here about the end of the range: `e #=> 4`.

Now consider the first element of the first element of `a`; that is, `3` (`4-k+1`). `3` appears in elements of `arr1` given by indices in the range `b..e`, where:

```
b = 3-1-2+1 #=> 1 
e = 3-1     #=> 2
```

We are only concerned here about the beginning of the range: `b #=> 1`.

We have now established that, for the example, the indices of elements of `arr1` that contain at least one element of any of the elements of `arr1` that contain `4` is given by the range:

```
1..4
```

We are left with:

```
stab(1,2,6,0).to_a #=> [1,2]
```

and

```
stab(1,2,6,5).to_a #=> [6,7]
```

More generally, for the integer `j`, this range is given by:

```
(j-k+1)-f-k+1..(j+k-1)-f
```

which simplifies to:

```
j-2*k-f+2..j+k-f-1
```

However, we need to ensure that the first index is non-negative and the last is less than `n`:

```
[j-2*k-f+2,0].max..[j+k-f-1,n-1].min
```

For the example, this tells us that if `j=4`, we can eliminate the elements of `arr` at indices:

```
[4-2*2-1+2,0].max..[4+2-1-1,5].min
  #=> 1..4
```

If `j=6`, we can the elements at indices:

```
[6-2*2-1+2,0].max..[6+2-1-1,5].min
  #=> 3..6
```

leaving only `arr1[0] #=> [1,2]`.

Therefore, you can obtain your desired result as follows:

```
def extract(f,k,n,arr2)
   arr2.reduce(n.times.to_a) do |a,j|
     a-([j-2*k-f+2,0].max..[j+k-f-1,n-1].min).to_a
   end.map { |i| stab(f,k,n,i).to_a }
end

arr2 = [4,6] 
extract(1,2,6,arr2)
  #=> [[1,2]]
```

Now consider the `arr1` I used for the second example above, which was specified by the following parameters:

```
f, k, n = 2, 3, 18
```

Suppose:

```
arr2 = [7,15]
```

Then

```
extract(f,k,n,arr2)
  #=> [[2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12], [18, 19, 20], [19, 20, 21]]
```

**Discussion**

This answer may seem analogous to swatting a fly with a hammer. I offer it for two reasons. The first is because I thought you might want to consider representing the array `arr1` in your application by the three parameters. That might be useful if the array is quite large, considering that elements can be constructed as needed, using the method `stab`. The second reason is merely the challenge of working it out.